Run multiple mpi command with gnu screen
I dont manage to send multiple mpirun command with one screen, while I manage to send multiple screen command with one mpirun command.
In the following run="...$i..." is a mpirun command like mpirun -np ... with a very long list of argument where $i are denoting some config file.
If I do
for i in 6 8 10
do
    run="...$i..."
    screen -S ${caseName} -L -Logfile ${logfileName} -dm bash -c "${run}"
done

it works!...
but it sends all the jobs at the same time and overloads the computer which is used for other tasks... it is annoying. So I tried this
screen -dmS "${sessionName}" bash -c "exec bash"
for i in 6 8 
    run="...$i..."
    screen -S "${sessionName}" -X stuff "$run \n"
done

but it doesn't work. If the for loop is running over one value only it runs.
What is wrong with the second screen ?
Is it possible to write a script which is chaining the mpirun command with screen?

Are you sure it's not an issue of exiting screen? You could redirect the output somewhere and throw the process to the background if you want to check this theory.
